# How to increase the space between a section/subsection title and a theorem

Tags: spacing, titlesec, amsthm, ntheorem, vertical-spacing

I would like to add some space between a theorem and the preceding line.

I used `titlesec` and `amsthm` to customise the spacing but when the theorem is just after a subsection, the required spacing before the theorem is not respected.

How to increase the space between a section/subsection title and a theorem?

---

Here is a MWE showing the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

% -------------------------------------------------- %
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\bigskip\bfseries\large}
  {\Roman{section}. }
  {0em}
  {#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\smallskip\bfseries}
  {\arabic{subsection}) }
  {0em}
  {#1}
  
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\itshape}
  {{\normalfont\alph{subsubsection})}}
  {.5em}
  {#1}

\titlespacing{\section}{0.5ex}{*1}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0.5ex}{*2}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0.5ex}{*0}{*0}
% -------------------------------------------------- %


% -------------------------------------------------- %
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem-style}
  {3pt}% space before
  {3pt}% space after
  {\itshape}
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% header font
  {.\vspace{0.5mm}}% punctuation
  {\newline}% after theorem header
  {}% header specification (empty for default)

\theoremstyle{theorem-style}

\newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}
% -------------------------------------------------- %


\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}

\begin{proposition}
This proposition is too close to the title.
\end{proposition}

\subsection{Subsection}

Some text.

\begin{proposition}
This proposition is not too close to the preceding line.
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

Following an idea given in  the comments, I've tried

```
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\smallskip\bfseries}
  {\arabic{subsection}) }
  {0em}
  {#1}
  [\strut\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Section etc. uses `\@afterheading` which treats the next line special (no page break, no indentation). Try adding an invisible line of text, like `\strut\vspace{-\baselineskip}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for your hint. Do you know where I should add this `\strut\vspace{-\baselineskip}`?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I've tried (see the edit), but it does not work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You seem to be uncertain about using `ntheorem` and `amsthm`… This question has `amsthm`, the most recent one of yours has `ntheorem`. I'd have no doubt and always use `amsthm`.

Comment: Add `\noindent` before `\begin{proposition}` in the case it comes just after a section title. And never start a sectional unit with a theorem statement.

Answer (score 1):

`\@afterheading` expects a normal paragraph to follow.  This provides an invisible one instead.  Only use where needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

% -------------------------------------------------- %
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\bigskip\bfseries\large}
  {\Roman{section}. }
  {0em}
  {#1}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\smallskip\bfseries}
  {\arabic{subsection}) }
  {0em}
  {#1}
  
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\itshape}
  {{\normalfont\alph{subsubsection})}}
  {.5em}
  {#1}

\titlespacing{\section}{0.5ex}{*1}{1ex}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0.5ex}{*2}{*0}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0.5ex}{*0}{*0}
% -------------------------------------------------- %


% -------------------------------------------------- %
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{theorem-style}
  {3pt}% space before
  {3pt}% space after
  {\itshape}
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% header font
  {.\vspace{0.5mm}}% punctuation
  {\newline}% after theorem header
  {}% header specification (empty for default)

\theoremstyle{theorem-style}

\newtheorem*{proposition}{Proposition}
% -------------------------------------------------- %


\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection}\strut\vspace{-\baselineskip}

\begin{proposition}
This proposition is too close to the title.
\end{proposition}

\subsection{Subsection}

Some text.

\begin{proposition}
This proposition is not too close to the preceding line.
\end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for an automatic solution.

Comment: Not possible with titlesec.  OTOH you could modify \proposition using etoolbox and \pretocmd or \AtBeginEnvifonment.